# How to save video frames to new folder

Tags: python, opencv

I was wondering how to run a loop so that all the videos in a file have their frames extracted and saved to a new file. So far I have the following code:

```
import cv2
import os

# where the videos are stored
path = "/Users/harryhat/Desktop/Water Droplets/Videos of water droplets/Random"

for video_path in os.listdir(path):
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(video_path)
    if ext == '.avi':
        video_path = os.path.join(path, video_path)

        # Opens the Video file
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
        i = 0
        while(cap.isOpened()):
            ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret == False:
            break
        cv2.imwrite(str(name)+str(i)+'.jpg', frame)
        i += 1
        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

However at the moment when I run it nothing happened, ideally each video would have their frames extracted and placed in a file which had the videos name in it. Any pointers on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do in this way

```
import cv2
import os
count=1

vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')
def getFrame(sec):
    vidcap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC,sec*1000)
    hasFrames,image = vidcap.read()
    if hasFrames:
        dim = (512, 512) # you can change image height and image width
        resized = cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
        cv2.imwrite("images/"+str(count)+".png", resized) # image write to image folder be sure crete image folder in same dir
    return hasFrames
sec = 0
frameRate = 0.1 # change frame rate as you wish, ex : 30 fps => 1/30

success = getFrame(sec)
while success:
    count = count + 1
    sec = sec + frameRate
    sec = round(sec, 2)
    success = getFrame(sec)
```

If this helps you give